# Recompiling Sass assets in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, compass-sass, sprockets

I'm working on a rails app where we want to allow the user to use an admin tool to create new themes. The admin tool is a separate application and communicates with our main application through a database. My problem is that I've written custom Sass extensions to load our data into our style sheets, but once that is done, I am unable to recompile the assets in our production environment.

So far I've seen two possibilities for this:

1.Increment the version of config.assets.version. So I have this code:

```
MyApp::Application.assets.version = 
       (MyApp::Application.config.assets.version.to_i + .1)
```

From what I've read incrementing this should cause the assets to recompile, but it seems to only work when it is incremented by hand and the server is restarted.

2.Create a compiler and tell it to clean up the old assets and recompile them:

```
compiler = Compass::Compiler.new(
                    Rails.root.to_s,
                    Compass.configuration.sass_path,
                    Compass.configuration.css_path,
                    {:sass => Compass.sass_engine_options} )
compiler.clean!
compiler.run
```

With this method, however, I run into the problem that the Sprockets::Index.expire_index! method raises an error when I try to create a new compiler.

Yes, I do understand that I can set the assets to recompile on every request, but the performance hit is not something we want. Also, since this is a theme, the data should not be changing often, so we only need to recompile when the admin chooses to save the new theme.

So, finally, my question is: Are there any other possible methods to do what I want? Or am I going down the right path, and if so, where am I going wrong?

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that since we are using Sass functions to change the values of the stylesheets, even if I do turn on the option to compile in production, it won't work. Since the actual stylesheets will never change.

Answer (score 4):

Rails has a Rake task that does asset compilation for you. You should run it once every time you deploy your application to your production environment.

`rake assets:precompile`

The compiled assets are output to `public/assets`. For more details, check out the [Rails Asset Pipeline Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets).